# How do I change the value of an imported variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

```
import Foo from 'file'

if (inDevelopment) {
  Foo = null
}
```

I would like to do this, but it results in

`SyntaxError: "Foo" is read-only`

Is there anything that changes the default const behavior, like `let import Foo from 'file'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Use a second variable:

```
import Foo from 'file'

const LocalFoo = inDevelopment ? null : Foo;
```

Only the module that exported the variable can change its value, although non-constant exports are weird to work with.